# How to send request one by one?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a service like this. The Client request is a multiple records. 
For example, the client request is :

```
parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4, parameter5
parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4, parameter5
parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4, parameter5
parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4, parameter5
```

I need send this records to real service one by one. How to do this in WSO2?

Answer (score 2):

In that case you can use callout mediator with the iterate mediator. 
Where in the iteration you can iterate over Each set of parameters and in the iterate target you can do a call out (use Callout mediator) to the service using the each set of parameters.

You need to set the sequential parameter to true in [iterate mediator](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/mediators/iterate.html) so that it will be invoked one after another. and Call Out mediator invocation is a blocking call. So it will block till response comes. see [callout mediator](http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/mediators/callout.html)

I'll be able to give more details if you could provide the exact message format. Sample message will be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I assume You data is in a format like

```
<data>
<record>param1</record>
<record>param2</record>
<record>param3</record>
<record>param4</record>
</data>
```

If that is the case and your requirement is to send this data one by one iterating through elements one by one. You can use iterate mediator of WSO2 ESB and iterate through parameters and send them one by one. You will have to set the parameter "sequential" to true in the iterate mediator to make it single threaded.

see http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/advanced_mediation_samples.html#Splitter

cheers,
Charith

Answer (score 0):

Answering would be easier if you elaborate more on your specific requirement. So, I'm assuming that your requirement is to send some values coming from client to the service in sequential manner. For that, you can simply extract whatever the parameters comes in the request (as properties using property mediator) and then sequentially invoke the service with each parameter. (send mediator with receive sequence)

Comment: Thank you very much. The above example have 4 records, I send the first line parammeters(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4, parameter5),after service response, I send the second line parameters..... I need send this one by one. How do do?